# Error in logout from Android Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to logout from my Android Facebook app. I am getting an issue in logout as it gives me the following error:

```
{"error_code":101,"error_msg":"Invalid API key","request_args": [{"key":"method","value":"auth.expireSession"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}
```

If I use the same code on back button to logout then it works properly.

I checked my api key and generated new hash key and app id but still it is not working.

Comment: I am getting the same problem. Have you fixed it?

Comment: facing the same issue. any reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

This also happens to me.

I make singleton class for working with facebook api, call login in one fragment (this fragment destroys after) and call logout in another fragment. But when login fragment destroys, singleton also gone away (dalvik behaviour), so at logout singleton recreates with null access_token.

Finded it, reworked my singleton and now it logouts normally.
So debug your app and watch if access token is available at logout.